# MyBatis + PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, mybatis

I'm attempting to perform a radial search of database rows in a PostgreSQL database using MyBatis as an object mapper to return Java objects. Connection and all queries work as expected, except the radial search. I've installed PostGIS in the DB. Queries are set up in XML configuration files. The troublesome query is...

```
select * from "Events"
    where (ST_DWithin("CreationLocation"::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(#{longitude}, #{latitude}), 4326)::geography, #{radius})
    and "Tag" = 0 and "EventTime" >= now())
```

If I connect directly to the database using PGAdmin and run the query with the same parameters that are passed in to the mapper, I get multiple (correct) results. When the mapper runs the query, I get no results. I believe this has to do with the prepared statements of MyBatis but I don't know more than that.

Comment: What does the PostgreSQL log file show when you issue the query from MyBatis?

Comment: The prepared statement *MyBatis* ends up using should ultimately be similar to the way raw *JDBC* works... What's the actual query that *MyBatis* is creating? You can enable logging of that via the **DEBUG** level, more details at https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/logging.html (logging via *Postgres*, as Patrick mentioned, would also shed some light from a different perspective).

Answer (score 0):

Well I ultimately figured the issue out by changing ST_SetSRID(...) to

```
ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || #{longitude} || ' ' || #{latitude} || ')')
```

My assumption (though I haven't confirmed) is that the object mapper didn't know how to handle double-nested parameters, and it was just getting passed '?' instead of a real value for the lat and long.